# What is 'Windows host process(Rundll32)' and why is it using so much CPU?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, task-manager

[image]

Why is this process using my CPU so much, what is it doing in the secret? And how to fix this?
And I think it affects my other programs.

Comment: Could be anything. Go to the details tab, right click on the bar at the top that contains 'Name,Status...etc'. Click Select columns, tick command line. Then from this you can see what DLL its running.

Answer (score 2):

[Rundll32.exe is a tool to run functions from DLLs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/164787/info-windows-rundll-and-rundll32-interface).

> The Rundll and Rundll32 utility programs were originally designed only
>   for internal use at Microsoft. But the functionality provided by them
>   is sufficiently generic that they are now available for general use.

To see which DLL gets loaded, go to the `Details` tab of Taskmgr, do a rightclick on the column header, click on `Select columns` and activate commandline

[image]

Now look in comandline which DLL gets executed and if this is malware or legit Windows DLL.

Comment: How would we know a legit Windows DLL from others?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage this commandline shows the full path, open the folder, look at file properties if it has Microsoft signature. Sometime malware has legal names shell32.dll but they are stored in non system locations